# Is the integers ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} }$ a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

In mathematics,

a [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sequences_and_series) is

> a list of objects (or events) which have been ordered in a sequential
>   fashion

a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) is

> a collection of distinct objects, considered as an object in its own
>   right.

the integers ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} }$ is definitely a set.

is the integers ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} }$ a sequence? since the objects(elements) of the integers, is in ascending order.

Comment: A set is not a sequence. But if it's countable (as $\mathbb Z$) you can find a sequence that covers each element of the set.

Comment: but, if you're including negative integers, that sequence is not going to have the usual ascending order of integers

Answer (score 1):

For a sequence you need to specify the order, not just the elements.  $\Bbb Z$ with the usual order is not a sequence because it doesn't have a first element.  The Wikipedia definition continues "More formally, a sequence is a function with a domain equal to the set of positive integers."  We can certainly list the integers as a sequence
$$0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4\ldots$$
and in many other ways.

Comment: MIsleading answer. Also $\mathbb N$ is not a sequence, although it has a first element. BTW you can define an order on $\mathbb Z$ with a "first element".

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Indexing) also notes that bi-infinite sequences, e.g. $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb Z}$ or $(a_n)_{n=-\infty}^\infty$, are valid, so it doesn't seem the tenet of a "least element" (regardless of ordering) is strictly necessary (even if quite common).