# Is $(A_1,A_2,\dots ,A_n, \dots)$ where $n \in ℕ^*$ a legit sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

the comments on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3311113/660389) says

> $\mathbb N$ is not a sequence

I guess it is because set $\mathbb N$ does hot have an order with its element.

so, if I put an order on each element of that, to construct this

$(A_1,A_2,\dots ,A_n, \dots)$

$A_1 = 1, A_2 = 2, ..., A_n = n, ...$ where $n \in ℕ^*$ (positive integers)

Is $(A_1,A_2,\dots ,A_n, \dots)$ a legit sequence?

Comment: You're asking whether $1,2,3,\dots$ is a sequence? If it isn't, what is?

Comment: What is $\mathbb N^*$? What does the $^*$ mean?

Comment: @bof positive integers

Comment: Yes, $(A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n, \ldots)$ is a legit sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, they mean $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ aren't sequences, because they're just sets of some elements, and sequences are functions from naturals to a set. So, while formally the set $\{1,2,3,...\}$ is not a sequence, $(1,2,3,...)$ (or $a_n=n$, or formally $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),...\}$) is.

I see that comment as just nitpicking, formally $\mathbb{N}$ is not a sequence, because it's just a (unordered) set of distinct elements with no structure on them, but it becomes a sequence if we order, or number them.

Answer (score 0):

By definition `set` doesn't have order. That means that $\{1,2,3\}=\{2,1,3\}$
So $\{0,1,2,3,4\dots\}=\{2,1,0,3,4,5,6...\}=\mathbb N$
However you can use another thing: ordered group - the set and a relation on it.  $<A,\prec>$, Where A - is a set, and $\prec$ is some relation. [`<` is a private example of $\prec$]

This relation must be an `order relation`. That means $a\nprec a$ and $a\prec b \land b\prec c\rightarrow a\prec c$

Your suggestion is nothing nut $<\mathbb N, \prec >$ where $\prec$ is `<`.
It's a good idea, but it is not a simple $\mathbb N$ set.